# IronPython 2.7.8 with pip

Tags: python, pip, ironpython

After installed IronPython 2.7.8 (latest stable build) on Windows 10, I tried run pip but I got error like this:

```
PS C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7> ipy.exe -m pip install numpy
Unhandled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\runpy.py", line 187, in run_module
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1261, in setParseAction
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1043, in _trim_arity
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\runpy.py", line 81, in _run_module_code
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 4734, in <module>
IndexError: index out of range: -1
PS C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7>
```

I have no clue to solve this error. It seems to be problem of IronPython? I have no way to install packages to the IronPython hence, cannot do any development with that. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/issues/71
I found this issue tracked in github. 
You have to ensure you are using the correct version of pip which works with ipy 2.7.8

Comment: Please check the last comment`Well, the newer versions of pip don't work with IronPython 2.7.8, we should create a new issue to track that.` did you try installing without pip?

Comment: i tried easy_install as well but still does not work. I tried to use IronPython in VS 2017, and i do not know how to install package without the pip (as VS automatically called pip). Any advise?

Comment: if I try installing "without pip", what should I use and what is the recommended way?